# how to update form panel record in controller in sencha touch 2 using mvc?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I have a sample login form. In that there is a controller, view and a model.I would like to validate the form. my Form panel id is 'formPanelLogin' and have to update the form record in the controller. but this code "formPanelLogin.updateRecord (teamModel);" can't work and error message like "updateRecord is not define".
 Please give me an answer for this problem. my code will following..

```
//Controller

Ext.define('MyApp.controller.mvcController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

            config: {
                        refs: {
                                    BtnSubmit: "#btnSubmit",
                                    BtnCancel:"#btnCancel",
                                    BtnPromoHome:"#PromotionsBtnHome",
                                    BtnThirdBack:"#thirdBtnBack",
                                    BtnSecondBack:"#btnUnderHoodService",                                   
                              },
                        control: {
                                    BtnSubmit:
                                                {
                                                    tap: "onBtnSubmitTap"
                                                },
                                    BtnCancel: 
                                                {
                                                    tap: "onBtnCancelTap"
                                                },
                                    BtnPromoHome:
                                                {
                                                    tap: "onBtnPromoHomeTap"
                                                },
                                    BtnSecondBack:
                                                {
                                                    tap: "onBtnSecondBackTap"
                                                },
                                    BtnThirdBack:
                                                {
                                                    tap: "onBtnThirdBackTap"
                                                }
                                }
                    },

                    onBtnCancelTap: function (options)
                    {   
                        //formPanelLogin.reset();                                       
                        var teamModel = Ext.create('MyApp.model.MyModel'),
                                    errors, errorMessage = '';                                  
                                    formPanelLogin.updateRecord (teamModel);
                                    errors = teamModel.validate();
                                    if (!errors.isValid()) {
                                    errors.each(function (err) {
                                        errorMessage += err.getMessage() + '<br/>';
                                    }); // each()
                                    Ext.Msg.alert('Form is invalid!', errorMessage);
                                } else {
                                    Ext.Msg.alert('Form is valid!', '');
                                } // if         
                        console.log("Cancel");  
                    },
});


//view


Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',

    config: {
        layout: 
            {
                type: 'card'                
            },          
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                id: 'panelOuter',
                layout: 
                    {
                        type: 'card',
                        animation:
                        {
                            type: 'slide'                                                                                                                                                                                   
                        }
                    },          
                items: [
                {
                 xtype: 'panel',    
                 items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'toolbar',
                        docked: 'top',
                        title: 'MVC',
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'button',
                                docked: 'left',
                                id: 'btnBack'                               
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'button',
                                docked: 'right',                                
                                id: 'btnHome'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'formpanel',
                        docked: 'top',
                        height: 117,
                        id: 'formPanelLogin',
                        scrollable: true,
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'fieldset',
                                id: 'loginform',
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                        label: 'UserName',
                                        name: 'userName',
                                        labelWidth: '40%',
                                        name: 'usernameField',
                                        placeHolder: '...... Type here .......',
                                        required: true
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'passwordfield',
                                        label: 'Password',
                                        labelWidth: '40%',
                                        required: true
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        height: 45,
                        id: 'btnPanel',
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'button',
                                docked: 'right',
                                id: 'btnSubmit',
                                ui: 'action-small',
                                width: 85,
                                text: 'Submit'                              
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'button',
                                docked: 'right',
                                id: 'btnCancel',
                                ui: 'decline-small',
                                width: 85,
                                text: 'Cancel'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
        ]}
                ]
            },
});

//model

Ext.define('MyApp.model.MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {

         fields : [
                    {
                        name: 'userName',
                        type: 'string'
                    }, 
                    {
                        name: 'password',
                        type: 'string'
                    }
                  ],
                   validations: [
                                    {
                                        field: 'userName',
                                        type: 'presence',
                                        message: 'User Name is required.'
                                    }
                                ]
    }
});
```

Comment: Agree. Accept answers to questions you have asked already. People won't put in the effort to answer your question if there's no reward. When you accept answers, people get reputation points

Comment: Totally agree. Keep asking, getting good answer and leaving WITHOUT `visible` thanks is not recommended here.

Comment: pls help to answer this problem...